# Share Google Sheets Anonymously

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, privacy, google-drive-sharing

Is there a way to share Google Sheets(programmatically or otherwise) without revealing the Owner's name/Email address to the public/link receivers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to give the permission of viewer and editor to users for the shared spreadsheet, you are required to share the endpoint like `https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/### fileId ###/edit?usp=sharing`. In this case, users can retrieve your information including name and email from file ID using `GET https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/### fileId ###?key={YOUR_API_KEY}` of Drive API. Namely, it means that the method using the file ID gives the owner information to others. So how about this workaround?

1. When the spreadsheet is [published to web](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/183965), the URL is like `https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/### Not fileId ###/pubhtml`. In this case, users cannot retrieve the file ID. So users cannot know the owner information.

   - In this case, the shared URL is like `https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/### Not fileId ###/pubhtml`.
2. Display the spreadsheet using [Web Apps](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web). In this case, users cannot retrieve file ID, because the owner information cannot be retrieved from the Web Apps URL.

   - In this case, In thiscase, the shared URL is like `https://script.google.com/macros/s/### Not fileId ###/exec`.
3. Display the spreadsheet using [Google Visualization API](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/spreadsheets) and API key. In this case, users cannot retrieve file ID, because the owner information of the API key cannot be retrieved.

   - In this case, the shared URL is the URL of your own site.

I also think that there are other methods other than that mentioned in my answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Your answer is perfect. I don't think there's any other way though. I tried publishing and yes, It's not the same ##file ID## , but the `###Not file id###` is constant per Workbook. I tried to find some connection to decrypt the  `###Not file id###`  to `###fileID####`, but was unsuccessful. Because it would be a potential loop hole. If you ever find a way, keep me and this post updated. Another issue is search engine and caching/indexing by search engines, when publicly sharing on the web. You can't share only to people with links. But this is the best answer. Thanks again!!

Comment: @I'-'I I had tried to convert from it to file ID before. But I couldn't do it. So I thought that this can be used for the situation you need. If you want to publish a special sheet, you can do it by selecting the sheet when it publishes. If you want to select from the published whole sheet, the file ID is required to be used. The URL is like ``https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/cells/[file ID]/[sheetId]/public/values?alt=json``.

Comment: @I'-'I And if you don't want to be cached by search bot, how about using Web Apps? In this case, you can use ``googlebot`` and ``robots`` of meta tag. Is my understanding for your comment correct?

Comment: `The URL is like https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/cells/[file ID]/[sheetId]/public/values?alt=json. – Tanaike 4 mins ago` 1.Do you mean fileID can be used to publicly access, if the sheet was published?  2. But, still `#Not file ID#` cannot be converted to `#file ID#` Right??

Comment: @I'-'I Yes. When the spreadsheet is published to web, you can access to it using the file ID of spreadsheet. But the URL which is retrieved by publishing spreadsheet doesn't include file ID. So only users who know file ID can use it using the URL with file ID.

Comment: Great. But, Since Google doesn't mention this officially anywhere, I guess They might change this in the future, at their own will. Thanks again. Have a nice day!!

Comment: @I'-'I I could know it from [ref1](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/v3/data#retrieve_a_cell-based_feed) and [ref2](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/v3/worksheets#sheets_api_urls_visibilities_and_projections). Although I might see other site, I forgot about them. I'm sorry. I also think that Google's manuals are a bit difficult for me. There might be some users who feel the same with me.

Comment: Thanks. That's good reference(been reading that till now). If you don't mind, Have you found any other "documentation" for why or how  the published URL ID is different from spreadsheet ID? We know that it's different, But is there any documentation? I read that: Before 2009, both IDs were the same.

Comment: @I'-'I I couldn't notice about it. So I had never seen about it yet. If I found it, I will tell you.

Comment: @I'-'I Wow! I am surprising this. I would like to study and support for reflecting this. Thank you so much.

Comment: The answer was well researched and this question was always at the back of my head. You deserve this :)

Comment: `And if you don't want to be cached by search bot, how about using Web Apps? In this case, you can use googlebot and robots of meta tag.`  If I'm not mistaken, [all meta tags are ignored, expect these 4](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/html/html-output#addMetaTag(String,String)) So, It's not possible to add robots to web apps. Am I right?

Comment: @I'-'I I had seen [this](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/html/html-output-meta-tag) and I had not noticed your link. Although I cannot try it in my current environment, from your link, it was found that the information of my comment is wrong. I'm really sorry for my poor skill. If you think that my answer should be deleted, feel free to tell me.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.. It was just a comment. Just wanted to confirm. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the Google Sheets sharing option, people able to access the spreadsheet is able to find it on Google Sheets (https://sheets.google.com) and on Google Drive (https://drive.google.com). There they will be able to see the spreadsheet owner and the spreadsheet collaborators either by the file listing or by the file information panel.

One alternative is to publish the spreadsheet to the web but this will limit what spreadsheet features are available to your spreadsheet users.

Another alternative is to use Google Apps Script, the Google Sheets API or a tool like Awesome Tables to publish the spreadsheet data but also, this will not include most of the the Google Sheets features.