# How to share a Google Sheets demo spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-drive-sharing

I find a lot of -especially new- users on the site are having difficulties on sharing a demo sheet so they can be easily helped if any at all.

#### So, what is the right way to share a demo test sheet?

Comment: I like this a lot! It was very helpful with modifying my question. The only quibble I have is that this question's title may be taken to mean "How to share it with other people in general" instead of "how to share a sheet to help people answer a question more quickly/fully on WebApps."

Comment: @aschultz Well... Hmmm. I believe it will help other people as well. We are not the only site helping out. And anyway I wanted it to be brief and easy to remember. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Related: [Share Google Sheets Anonymously](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/114961/88163)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### The correct way to publicly share a Google test sheet

---

You have 2 options:

1. Share an already existing sheet **OR**
2. Create a brand new one under your existing or a new account.

**Please follow the steps:**

**Option 1**
Skip to ***"Prepare your sheet"***

**Option 2**

- #### Creating a new sheet:

  - A brand new sheet can be created by clicking [here](https://sheets.new) or  [here](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSeprZS3Al0n7JiVQIEiCi_Ad9FRXbpgB7x1-Wq6iAfdmVbWiA/viewform)
- #### Prepare your sheet.

  **Before** sharing your sheet **make sure you fill in** all the information needed. That is:

  - Include only but all necessary **demo data excluding any sensitive data**.
  - Not too little, not too much. Do not overload the sheet. No need to have 500 rows and 50 columns. As well as not just 2 rows and 1 column. **Just as much as needed**.
  - Place in the spreadsheet -as well as in the question- the essential **information for others to fully understand your issue**.
  - Give an **example of your expected results**.
  - Include your **efforts thus far**. *(It shows good will and determination)*
- #### Share your spreadsheet

  [image: Correct way to publicly share a Google test sheet]
- #### Let us know:

  After you shared your sheet, do let us know.

  - Check your answer for possible mistakes and **add additional clarifications** if any needed.
  - **Edit/Update your answer including the copied link** to the spreadsheet.
  - **Alert the person** who asked for it **by leaving a comment** for them **under your question** *(@name some text)*.
  - **Do NOT just add the link in the comment**
- #### Privacy Note:

  Sharing your spreadsheet [exposes your email address](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/394304/1330560). If you'd like your email address to be *"more private"*, you can try the [Blank sheet maker](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSeprZS3Al0n7JiVQIEiCi_Ad9FRXbpgB7x1-Wq6iAfdmVbWiA/viewform) created by  members of Google products experts program shared by [@Mattking](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/users/238008/mattking). *You would still need to trust and share your email with those members, but your email is not public to everyone*.
  Alternatively, you can create a dummy  Google account for sharing sheets, forms, documents, etc. to the stackexchange sites.

## Related

- [Share Google Sheets Anonymously](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/114961/)

Comment: By sharing a spreadsheet, a questioner is also publicly exposing their email address. I suggest that you add a warning to your answer along the lines that "You should be aware that sharing your spreadsheet will unavoidably expose your email address.""

Comment: @Tedinoz _(Please correct me if I am wrong.)_ I believe your observation is incorrect. **What is shown is** the name one chose to be publicly shown under one's Google account.  **Most certainly neither one's email nor one's real name.**

Comment: I do understand your comment, and it was certainly news to me when it was  brought to my attention. This post on [StackOverflow Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/394304/1330560) has the instructions- the one's regarding using the api. Let me know how you get on.

Comment: @Tedinoz _(Sorry for the late reply.)_ I believe the [answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/394305) says it all. In any case, using the word "ethical" (which includes and mainly used about morality issues) is completely out of context (see moral vs ethical or ethical vs unethical). So the question posed is the best example itself. Meaning, instead of trying to explain in chat or endless comments going back and forth what the -usually- newcomer wants, one asks for a "demo sheet" which has nothing to do with ethics.

Comment: The problem with sharing it editable is that anyone can trash the sheet. Surely it's better just to share it read-only and let people make their own copies to work on?

Comment: @PhilHibbs Since **I find your concern to be completely genuine that extends to any file stored in a Google Drive**, I decided to turn it to a full-fledged question. Please find the **answer [here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/153628/117311)**

Comment: @marikamitsos I didn't mean "deleted", I meant trashed in the sense of "wrecked, destroyed, made useless".

Comment: @marikamitsos This tool i made might be of interest to you all on this thread:
https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSeprZS3Al0n7JiVQIEiCi_Ad9FRXbpgB7x1-Wq6iAfdmVbWiA/viewform I realize it's not a complete solution and that people would have to trust me that I've deleted their emails, but it's quite a bit less exposure than a traditional shared sheet.

Comment: @MattKing Sure Matt. If I remember correctly you also had a post about it in Google Forums (if you could share the link). Although I think that the raised concerns have gone out of proportion, I do welcome every tool that can further help anonymity. I could include it when I update the post.

Comment: `Most certainly neither one's email nor one's real name.` **Certainly true. Email address is public, if sheet is public and will be shared and may be easily linked with SO account by bots**

Comment: @MattKing How does your link work exactly?  PS: You should probably add a link somewhere in the form to link back to a "About" page or something.

Comment: @marikamitsos I tried to explain how it works in the introduction on the Form itself.  Maybe I wasn't clear enough?  It creates a blank editable sheet owned by the bot, and emails you a link for it.  You can then share that sheet freely without worrying about exposing your identity to the internet at large.  The sheet automatically turns View Only after 30 days.

Answer (score 7):

Other than [the privacy issues](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/394304) mentioned in [the previous answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383), the biggest weakness of sharing spreadsheets is that they can be un-shared any time. Any question depending solely or partly on external links isn't worthy of any stackexchange site including webapps. There are other better alternatives to sharing a spreadsheet. In my opinion, using tables is the best option. This answer deals with neat ways to create such tables.

All you need to create a table is a simple formula:

- Formula:

  ```
  =ARRAYFORMULA("|"&TO_TEXT(A1:C8))
  ```

  If you want to share `A1:C8`, use the above formula in a another tab. To use formula, the second row `A2:C2` should only contain dashes `--` in all the cells, while `A1:C1` acts as a header.

  - If `A1:C7` looked like this:

  ```
  Item 1  Item 2  Item 3        
  food    chips   
  drinks  beer    coffee
  food    chips   
  food    chips   
  drinks  beer    coffee
  drinks  beer    coffee
  ```

  - Add a empty row with `--` under the header row:

  ```
  Item 1  Item 2  Item 3
  --      --      --
  food    chips   
  drinks  beer    coffee
  food    chips   
  food    chips   
  drinks  beer    coffee
  drinks  beer    coffee
  ```

  - In a empty range or a another sheet, use the formula `=ARRAYFORMULA("|"&TO_TEXT(A1:C8))`, you'll get:

  ```
  |Item 1 |Item 2 |Item 3
  |--     |--     |--
  |food   |chips  |
  |drinks |beer   |coffee
  |food   |chips  |
  |food   |chips  |
  |drinks |beer   |coffee
  |drinks |beer   |coffee
  ```

  - Now, copy and paste it into your question. **Make sure to paste it after two empty lines. And add two more empty lines at the bottom**(Even if you think it works as seen from the preview, it won't show up in your real post without those empty lines). It'll automatically show as a table:

  | Item 1 | Item 2 | Item 3 |
  | --- | --- | --- |
  | food | chips |  |
  | drinks | beer | coffee |
  | food | chips |  |
  | food | chips |  |
  | drinks | beer | coffee |
  | drinks | beer | coffee |
- Script: If formulas are hard, you can use [this script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66772209) by [Cooper](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7215091/cooper). It comes with a user interface with various customization options:

  - Go to Extensions > Apps Script
  - Copy paste [the three files](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66772209) into the editor

    - [`redact.gs`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66772209)
    - `redacttable.html`
    - `tableMarkdown.html`
    - You can create new files by clicking the `+` button on the left pane of the script editor. Note that `.gs` file is a script file and `.html` files are html files. When creating a new file, make sure it has a appropriate extension.
    - Save all files by clicking save button
  - Go back to your spreadsheet and refresh the page
  - You'll get a menu item named `Redactable table`. Click it and follow the instructions as shown:
    [image](GIF from https://stackoverflow.com/a/66772209 by [Cooper](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7215091/cooper))
- Addons: Addons like [this](https://workspace.google.com/marketplace/app/generatemarkdowntable/23306117760) helps in creating markdown tables easily.
- Formatting guide: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/356997/

Comment: If any one needs any help with code mods feel free to ask.  There are some things That just can't be displayed in the mark up tables that can be in a spreadsheet.

Comment: Dumb question: where should I use the formula printed above ("=ARRAYFORMULA("|"&TO_TEXT(A1:C8))")? I tried the conditional formatting in Google Sheets but it didn't seem to have any effect. I'm tempted to use Cooper's script, but honestly I'd like to learn how to use formula as printed above. Need this to correctly format a different StackExchange question...!

Comment: @ReverendSpeed As written `In a empty range or a another sheet`. Say in A10 of the same sheet.